# Specify image format for different different outputs

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I'm working on a Knitr markdown document which I want to output to both PDF and HTML.  In my knitr setup I have

```
opts_chunk$set(dev=c('pdf', 'png'))
```

and so both image formats are correctly generated when I run the code.

If the output document format is PDF, then everything works fine.  But when I compile it to HTML, it tries to use the PDF image rather than the PNG.

Is there a way to specify which image format to use for a given output document format, for example in the YAML header?

Comment: You can just use rmarkdown (http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) and you don't need to take care of these technical details: rmarkdown will use png for HTML and pdf for LaTeX/PDF output automatically. No need to set up anything.

Comment: Thanks Yihui.  That's actually actually the set-up I'm using but the HTML document just has a big missing image where I'd expect the PNG to be.

Comment: I was saying you did not need to set it up, i.e. you should remove this line.